# Multiple Overlaying UIViews

Tags: swift, uiview, xcode-storyboard

I'm working with a bunch of overlapping UIViews, I'm having to move the layers up and down in the document outline to edit in the storyboard. I'm using them for a tricky auto layout and I have a couple conditional ones that hide and show. Is that the best way to do it? It would be nice if you could hide/show the views as layers.

Thanks.

Keith

Answer (score 2):

Put your mouse over the section with overlapping layers.

Shift + Right click

You'll now have a contextual menu from which you can select the object you want to interact with. The properties for this view are visible in the inspector, and you can interact with this view without changing its position in the hierarchy.

Alternatively, you can select the item from the Document outline in the left hand side of the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not know about that menu select, that will come in handy. But I still can't clearly see what I'm editing behind the top overlay unless I move it's position temporarily.